# Убрать пустую полоску между двумя кнопками

Tags: html, css

Генерирую на сайте 2 кнопки из ссылок таким способом:

```css
.menu {
  font-family: 'Russo One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #383838;
  padding: 20px;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  user-select: none;
  background: #57b7df;
  position: relative;

}

.menu:hover {
  color: #57b7df;
  background: #383838;
}

.left {
  border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<a class="menu left" href="google.com">МЕНЮ</a><a class="menu" href="google.com">МЕНЮ</a>
```

И между ними вылазит пустой промежуток как на фото:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как его можно убрать? Если эмулировать этот же код во встроенном редакторе ruSO, то все отлично и пробела нет.

Comment: А пробелы или табуляция между этими ссылками есть?

Comment: @Cheg, нет, ничего нет

Comment: Попробуйте закомментировать промежуток между ссылками таким образом `<a>МЕНЮ</a><!----><a>МЕНЮ</a>`

Comment: @Cheg, не помогло, к сожалению

Comment: @erm Дайте линк на сайт. Где-то стиль накладывается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать убрать пустое место с помощью font-size: 0; для контейнера, и добавить font-size для внутреннего елемента. ПРосто для теста.

```css
.menu {
  font-family: 'Russo One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0;
  color: #383838;
  padding: 20px;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  user-select: none;
  background: #57b7df;
  position: relative;

}
.menu span {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.menu:hover {
  color: #57b7df;
  background: #383838;
}

.left {
  border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<a class="menu left" href="google.com"><span>МЕНЮ</span></a><a class="menu" href="google.com"><span>МЕНЮ</span></a>
```

Comment: К сожалению, это не решило проблемы

Comment: @erm в каком броузере наблюдается проблема, вы используэте normalize.css или reset.css?

Comment: Странно получилось, что когда я слова поменял на более длинные(которые и нужны будут), то все сошлось